# How can I install cc65 through apt?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

I am currently running Linux Mint 18.1, which I understand somehow inherits from Debian. I want to install cc65, which [seems to have been migrated to testing,](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/cc65) but I don't want any other packages from testing to get installed on my system.

How can I install cc65, but not any package from there willy-nilly?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to install it, but not from `debian testing`.

First, add this line to the end of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb     http://debian.trikaliotis.net/ stable contrib
```

Then you can add a gpg key (some kind of security measure I think):

```
wget -qO - www.trikaliotis.net/spiro.pgp | sudo apt-key add -
```

This command will download the key and add it. Then you can just `sudo apt-get update` to sync the repository and finally `sudo apt-get install cc65`

It's an older version than what's currently in debian testing. But hopefully this helps someone out.